# How to fix 'Value error' in Python(Using plotly)

Tags: python-3.x, plotly

I'm using plotly distribution in python, I'm creating a geographical graph of USA-States but when I try to execute the code I'm getting a 'Value error', I need help to fix this error

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs,init_notebook_mode,plot,iplot

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

 data = dict(type = 'choropleth',
location = ['AZ','CA','NY']
,locationmode = 'USA-states'
,colorscale = 'Portland',
text = ['text1','text2','text3'],
z=[1.0,2.0,3.0,]
,colorbar = {'title':'Colorbar title goes here'})

layout = dict(geo={'scope':'usa'})

choromap = go.Figure(data = [data],layout = layout)
```

Because I'm using a jupyter notebook I execute cell by cell,the code is not complete though the result I got is:

```
ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.Choropleth: 'location'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the example given at https://plot.ly/python/choropleth-maps/, The attribute is `locations`, and not `location`.
So the relevant code will change as below, from `location = ['AZ','CA','NY']` to `locations = ['AZ','CA','NY']`

```
data = dict(type = 'choropleth',
locations = ['AZ','CA','NY']
,locationmode = 'USA-states'
,colorscale = 'Portland',
text = ['text1','text2','text3'],
z=[1.0,2.0,3.0,]
,colorbar = {'title':'Colorbar title goes here'})
```